# Distance between the product of marginal distributions and the joint distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, distance, joint-distribution, proof, marginal-distribution

Given a joint distribution $P(A,B,C)$, we can compute various marginal distributions. Now suppose:
\begin{align}
P1(A,B,C) &= P(A) P(B) P(C)  \\
P2(A,B,C) &= P(A,B) P(C)  \\
P3(A,B,C) &= P(A,B,C)
\end{align}
Is it true that $d(P1,P3) \geq d(P2,P3)$ where d is the total variation distance?

In other words, is it provable that $P(A,B) P(C)$ is a better approximation of $P(A,B,C)$ than $P(A) P(B) P(C)$ in terms of the total variation distance? Intuitively I think it's true but could not find out a proof.

Comment: Why introduce $C$ at all? Upon dividing by $P(C)$ your question has nothing to do with $C$--and it looks trivial then.

Comment: @whuber $\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(C)} = P(A,B|C)$, so $C$ is still involved in $P3$.

Comment: @took: But $P3$ is just $P(A,B,C)$. So you are just really looking at $P(A,B)$ and $P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: @guest43434 I'm looking at the distances between the three distributions, so I think $P3$ is still relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find the following counter-example. Suppose $A,B,C$ are discrete variables. $A,B$ can each take two values while $C$ can take three values. 
The joint distribution $P(A,B,C)$ is:

\begin{array}{cccc}
A & B & C & P(A,B,C) \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0.1/3 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 0.25/3 \\
1 & 1 & 3 & 0.25/3 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0.4/3 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 0.25/3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 0.25/3 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0.4/3 \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 0.25/3 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 0.25/3 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 0.1/3 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0.25/3 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 0.25/3 \\
\end{array}

So the marginal distribution $P(A,B)$ is:
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & B & P(A,B) \\
1 & 1 & 0.2 \\
1 & 2 & 0.3 \\
2 & 1 & 0.3 \\
2 & 2 & 0.2 \\
\end{array}

The marginal distributions $P(A), P(B)$ and $P(C)$ are uniform.

So we can compute that:
\begin{align}
d(P1,P3) &= 0.1 \\
d(P2,P3) &= 0.4/3
\end{align}